# Python (almost fine): string splitter

Tags: python

I'm doing a lab to split an odd string and print out first half, middle char, second half. Code is working fine, except I can't get rid of the middle char when printing out the second half.
Here it is:

```
str = input("Enter an odd length string: ")
length = len(str)
middle = length // 2
half1 = str[ : middle ]
half2 = str[middle : ]
print("Middle character:",str[middle])
print("First half:",half1)
print("Second half:",half2)
```

The result is:

```
Enter an odd length string: Fortune favors the bold
Middle character: o
First half: Fortune fav
Second half: ors the bold
```

It is wrong because of that 'o'...

Any clues?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GhostOps That's not needed because the slice is exclusive of the end.

Comment: the problem is that the string has not always an even number of characters so you have to make a case study, even and odd

Comment: What about `abcd` ?

Comment: @azro The input is required to be odd length.

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the correct half2:

```
half2 = str[middle+1:]
```

with `ABCDE` as input:

```
string ='ABCDE'
length = len(string) # 5
middle = length // 2 # 2
half1 = string[:middle] # AB
half2 = string[middle+1:] # DE
middle_charachter = string[middle] # C
```

Answer (score 4):

Start the second half **after** the middle char as you don't want it there

```
half2 = value[middle + 1:]
```

---

In case you need to handle even length too

```py
def string_splitter(value):
    length = len(value)
    middle = length // 2
    half1 = value[: middle]
    half2 = value[middle:]

    if length % 2 == 1:
        half2 = value[middle + 1:]
        print("Middle character:", value[middle])

    print("First half:", half1)
    print("Second half:", half2)
```